# As a landlord Moving into as lodger of the tenant, in UK [complicated scenario]

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, landlord

I would like to check on one scenario.

We've rented out a flat that we own (and we have a residential mortgage on) through an Assured Shorthold Tenancy, via an agent.

Now as our situation has changed, we need to move back into our flat. We have served the current tenant with the statutory 2 months notice.

Now, because of urgency - we are thinking of negotiating with the current tenant to take-us as Guest / lodger (will pay them weekly) until their tenancy ends.

Also at the end of their tenancy, we would give them the option to stay for some more time as our lodger (if they want to).

If the tenant agrees to this arrangement, is it permitted? What issues could arise?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues, not personal finance.

Comment: If you check below link then could notice that there're many queries on renting. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rental-property

Comment: @user2451016 the other rental-property questions are all about the money side of renting, whereas at the moment this question is purely legal. I've edited your question for clarity; perhaps if you edited it further to ask something like "what would be a fair rate for us to pay the tenant" it would become on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to negotiate with your tenant. If you both agree, then you can do more-or-less what you want (subject to statutory limitations).

However, it's your flat, so it makes no sense for you to be both his landlord and lodger at the same time. Instead, why not negotiate with the tenant to end the tenancy now, and for him to become your lodger immediately?

Of course, he might just say no, and you can't force him to agree to this. So it might be best to have a back-up plan.